# CentOS 7 PAM Define Parameters for pam_pwquality

Tags: security, centos7, pam

Need to modify the "retry" attribute for pam_pwquality on a new CentOS 7 installation.

I would have expected this to been able to be done through modifying the /etc/security/pwquality.conf file and appending the `retry = x` parameter at the end of it, however, when trying a test password, I get an error message saying that retry is an invalid parameter.

The next step would be typically to modify the /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac file, but at the top of that, there's a line saying that that file is auto-generated.

Long story short... where am I supposed to put this updated parameter/change this parameter? Every online tutorial points to system-auth, but that can't be accurate, since that file gets re-generated when ever authconfig is ran, which would wipe out any of my changes. Is there a persistent place to put this thing?

Comment: Are you sure, that spaces are allowed? Try retry=x instead.

Answer (score 0):

The retry option is supposed to be in the system-auth, not in the /etc/security/pwquality.conf.